# How can I calculate the difference between each subsequent line of a text file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two feed bins (BinA, BinB) that output data via XML. Using Node, I can already successfully parse and log the relevant data to a text file every 5 minutes, see snippet:

```
(timestamp),(BinA current weight),(BinB current weight)

2020-06-16 13:49,4874,5578
2020-06-16 13:54,4871,5574
2020-06-16 13:59,4870,5573
```

Now, I want to calculate the "usage" every 5 minutes (between every line) and save it into another array. Subtracting the line below from the line above consecutively (4874-4871 = 3, 5578-5574 = 4,...) should result in this array:

```
(timestamp),(BinA minus line above),(BinB minus line above)
2020-06-16 13:54,3,4
2020-06-16 13:59,1,1
```

which is simple to load into a charts.js graph, and also generate alerts for over and under usage.

So far I'm getting nowhere with loops trying to come up with this data, and I haven't been able to find a similar problem/solution elsewhere.

Files for those interested (xml, data1.txt, app.js: 
[https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q6z7735bhy2k7fh/AACaai717meRVvzxj9LxVBLda?dl=0][1]

Btw, this is my first Node/Javascript project! (inspired by a problematic chicken barn)

Comment: In the first snippet, it's every 5 mins, not 10 mins?

Comment: Pardon me, corrected.

Comment: Could you explain how the second snippet is derived from the first one?

Comment: Basically it's line 1 minus line 2, and line 2 minus line 3 if that makes sense. Let me see if I can clarify that better.

Comment: The resulting array will always have one less line than the original.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of what you have coded so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. First of all format your data so it's in an array of objects, `timeStamp` being a string and `binA` and `binB` being numbers. You can convert the bin values to numbers if they are strings by doing this: `Number('4874')`.

Then call a function every five minutes and find the last item in the array, and push a new object in to a new array that is derived by comparing it with the object in the array before it:

```js
const usage = [];

const data = [
  {timeStamp: '2020-06-16 13:49', binA: 4874, binB: 5578},
  {timeStamp: '2020-06-16 13:54', binA: 4871, binB: 5574},
  {timeStamp: '2020-06-16 13:59', binA: 4870, binB: 5573},
]; 

const getUsage = data => {
  const result = {
    timeStamp: data[data.length - 1].timestamp,
    binA: data[data.length - 1].binA - data[data.length - 2].binA,
    binB: data[data.length - 1].binB - data[data.length - 2].binB,
  }
  usage.push(result);
}

// call getUsage(data); every five minutes
```

You should do this in parallel to parsing to text file, I wouldn't try to do this pulling the data from a text file.